# Unable to perform branch, database update error thrown

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, source-control-explorer

I am trying to branch a directory in TFS using the Source Control explorer, however whenever I do, I always get this error:

> TF400962: There was a database update error. Please try your operation again.

This occurs after confirming I would like to branch after it informs me that it will be committed as a single operation, pending changes will not be created and that it cannot be canceled when it is started.

[image]

I have been stuck on this for a while now and I can't seem to find any solution to this, here is a list of things I have tried.

- Made sure the Target Branch Name is below 255 characters ([As suggested here](http://myteamfoundationserver.blogspot.co.uk/2017/04/tf400962-there-was-database-update.html)). I also made sure the whole path on my machine was also less than 255 characters.
- Changed workspaces.
- Updated Visual Studio to the latest version.
- Restarted Visual Studio.
- Restarted my machine.
- Branched another directory (To see if the directory I need to branch isn't throwing the error).
- Made sure connection to the TFS server was correct.
- Checked that I had the correct settings in the workspace.
- Downloaded the directory I am trying to branch to my PC.

I have ran out of ideas and it really is frustrating me. Any help would be appreciated. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise now running on the latest updates.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you had a deleted branch in the path you are trying to branch to.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Have code at $/path/to/main
2. Branch from $/path/to/main to $/another/path/dev
3. Delete $/another/path/dev
4. Try to branch from $/path/to/main to $/another/path/dev/branch
   -> **TF400962**

Problem seems to be that $/another/path/dev/branch overlaps with deleted branch $/another/path/dev

Resolution:

5. Show deleted elements in TFS Explorer
6. Convert deleted branch $/another/path/dev/branch to regular folder
7. Branch from $/path/to/main to $/another/path/dev/branch
   -> **Success**!

Comment: Step 5. additional info: To Show deleted elements in TFS - Tools > Options > Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation Server and check "Show deleted items in the source control explorer." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/delete-restore-files-folders?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting a generic error that could happen because of any TFS SQL Server related issue. Please check events logs on your TFS's SQL server machine. You might find more information there.

There is more information here

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1128642/tf400962-there-was-a-database-update-error-please-try-your-operation-again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your TFS DB is not out of disk space.